# Creating extended property using EWS and access it from Outlook Add-in

Tags: delphi, exchange-server, outlook-addin, extended-properties, user-defined-fields

I am currently working on EWS to have some integration of our company application with Exchange 2010.  I am using EWS to create appoinment to Exchange 2010 and it works fine; but recently I tried to add some custom/extended property when creating the appointment, below is my code to add the extended property.

```
Dim customField As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "MyCustomField", MapiPropertyType.String)

appointment.SetExtendedProperty(customField, "CustomFieldValue")
```

The above codes able to create the custom field to the appointment.

Now here is my problem.  When I open up the appointment in Outlook that I created and go to "Developer > Design This Form", then "All Fields" tab, I only see the custom field I created in the "User-defined field in folder" but not in "User-defined field in this item".

I also making an Outlook Add-in to react to the custom field that I created using the EWS when user opens up the appointment in Outlook, when I tried to look for the custom field, couldn't find the custom field, because the custom field is created in "User-defined field in folder" but not in "User-defined field in this item".

This is the codes in the Outlook Add-in and will execute when user opens an apointment in Outlook.  But because the custom field is not in "in this item", the .Find() returns Nothing.

```
Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
appt = TryCast(inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.AppointmentItem)
If appt.UserProperties.Find("MyCustomField") Is Nothing Then
    'Some action
Else
    'Some action
End If
```

What I want to achieve is to create an appointment with the custom field (extended property) using EWS, and then read the custom field (extended property) in Outlook Add-in when user open the appointment in Outlook.

EDIT:

The value that I assigned to the custom field using EWS is shown in the "User-defined field in folder".  How do I retrieve the value from my Outlook Add-in? Maybe I can retrieve the value and add the custom field to the item and with the value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/2a98b4ab-0fbc-4863-8303-48711a18a050

Can't access the extended property created by EWS using UserProperties.  But can access using PropertyAccessor.

```
outlookItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/yourProp")
```

Comment: Would you please explain how this answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as another answer showing some actual (Delphi) code, because that was missing from the first answer.
AAppointmentItem is an OLEVariant

```
const
   GUID_PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS = '{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
   cPublicStringNameSpace = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/' + GUID_PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS + '/';

var
   lPropertyAccessor: OleVariant;
   lSchemaName, lValue: String;

begin   
   // Use the PropertyAccessor because Outlook UserProperties() can't access the extended properties created by EWS 
   // Use the 'string subnamespace of the MAPI namespace' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868915.aspx)
   // with the PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS GUID from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905283%28v=office.12%29.aspx
   lPropertyAccessor := AAppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor;
   lSchemaName := cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLID;  // Name constants defined elsewhere
   try
      lSchemaName := cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLID;
      lValue := lPropertyAccessor.GetProperty(lSchemaName);
      lEvent.CustSyncTTID := StrToInt(lValue);
   except
   end;
   try
      lSchemaName := cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCTIME;
      lValue := lPropertyAccessor.GetProperty(lSchemaName);
      lEvent.CustSyncDate := UTCString2LocalDateTime(lValue);
   except
   end;
   try
      lSchemaName := cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCID;
      lValue := lPropertyAccessor.GetProperty(lSchemaName);
      lEvent.CustSyncEntryID := lValue;
   except
   end;
```

Note the many try excepts because we are doing late binding; 'early' would've been better
(http://blog.depauptits.nl/2012/04/safely-accessing-named-properties-in.html)

Also, We are retrieving multiple user properties, so GetProperties() is actually better.

FWIW, this was the old code using UserProperties (lProperty is OLEVariant)

```
lProperty := AAppointmentItem.UserProperties.Find(PROPERTY_TIMETELLID);
if IDispatch(lProperty) <> nil then
  lEvent.CustSyncTTID :=  lProperty.Value;
lProperty := AAppointmentItem.UserProperties.Find(PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCTIME);
if IDispatch(lProperty) <> nil then
  lEvent.CustSyncDate :=  lProperty.Value;
lProperty := AAppointmentItem.UserProperties.Find(PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCID);
if IDispatch(lProperty) <> nil then
  lEvent.CustSyncEntryID := lProperty.Value;
```

[Edited to add 2013-6-10]

And here is the code modified to handle all three properties at once using GetProperties ([as MS recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147573%28v=office.12%29.aspx)):

```
lPropertyAccessor := AAppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor;
lSchemas := VarArrayOf([cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLID,
                        cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCTIME,
                        cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCID]);
try
  lValues := lPropertyAccessor.GetProperties(lSchemas);
  if VarType(lValues[0]) <> varError then
     lEvent.CustSyncTTID := lValues[0];
  if VarType(lValues[1]) <> varError then
  begin
     lDT := lValues[1];
     lDT := TTimeZone.Local.ToLocalTime(lDT);
     lEvent.CustSyncDate := lDT;
  end;
  if VarType(lValues[2]) <> varError then
    lEvent.CustSyncEntryID := lValues[2];
except
end;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you always set your custom properties as strings and the convert them to the appropriate format (datetime and int) after reading? Would it not be easier to use the right type to begin with when you set the properties?

Comment: You are right, that is not necessary. Changed lValue to variant.